# Round number of a plugin output WordPress

Tags: javascript, arrays, wordpress, filter, rounding

A booking plugin shows prices as a number with 2 decimals.
As I cannot find a filter to hook into, i think i maybe i need a JS loop.

There are several properties on a page with prices like $123,45. I would like to round it to $123

The html of the prices is:

```
<span class="price"><span class="currency">$</span>"123,45<span>
```

I tried a loop, but i am not really good at JS:

```
  function roundPrice() {

let oldPrices = document.getElementsByClassName("price");

for (let i = 0; i < oldPrices.length; i++) {

    // strip $ of price
    oldPrices[i] = oldPrices[i].substr[1];

    // string to num
    oldPrices[i] = parseInt(oldPrices[i]);

    // round number
    let newPrice = Math.round(oldPrices[i]);

        return oldPrices[i] = newPrice;

    }
}

    roundPrice();
```

But this did not work. Is there a solution like this?

Thanks so much, Sam

Comment: Hi, in what sense did it not work? Did you get any output changed, or did the system crash or did you see any errors in your console.log. As this is Wordpress, could you tell us where you are running this code/hooking it into? Thanks.

Comment: I did not get any output. But in WP do you always have to use a hook? Is the function otherwise not called? That could be the problem, i could not find a hook for this.

Comment: Where did you put your code - in functions.php/in a plugin....?

Comment: in a file custom-js.js and i hooked it in in functions.php in wp_enqueue_scripts

Comment: Can you post your enqueue call so we can have a look? It may be your code is being called but a bit early. And what booking plugin is it?

Comment: Also could you check that the element you have shown which has class price actually does have the characters you show (is there an extra double quote??)

Comment: The enqueue is:
wp_enqueue_script('custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() .  '/../villagio-child/custom-js.js', array(), '1.0');
I hooked it in wp_enqueue_scripts

Comment: I checked but there is no extra double quote in the .price element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts to this question: how to write the function so it will change prices in the relevant DOM elements and how to get the function run in Wordpress.

Taking the first part, the code in the question had a few problems. The immediate main one is that `document.getElementsByClassName("price")` returns a collection of elements, not an array of strings.

Please look through this code to understand what has to be done to iterate through these elements and manipulate their HTML.

```js
function roundPrice() {
let oldPrices = document.getElementsByClassName("price");//this gives you the collection of elements which have class price

for (let i = 0; i < oldPrices.length; i++) {

    // Note: oldprices[i] is an element NOT a string
    let price = oldPrices[i].innerHTML;//this should give you <span class="currency">$</span>"123,45

    let priceArray = price.split('>');//this will give you an array and you want the last bit
    let oldPrice = priceArray.pop();

    
    //now you have the actual price, but with , where JS would expect .
    oldPrice = oldPrice.replace(',','.');
    
    //now you can do the rounding
    let newPrice = Math.round(Number(oldPrice));// NOT parseInt

    //now we put the new price back into the element's innerHTML
    priceArray.push(newPrice);

    //then we write the innerHTML back into the element
    oldPrices[i].innerHTML = priceArray.join('>');
    }
}
//it would be a good idea to put some prefix of your own on this function name so it doesn't clash with any other plugin using function round
    roundPrice();
```

```html
<span class="price"><span class="currency">$</span>1234567,89</span>
<span class="notprice"><span class="currency">$</span>9999,01</span>
<span class="price and some"><span class="currency">$</span>888</span>
<span class="price"><span class="currency">$</span>123,45</span>
<span class="price"><span class="currency">$</span>123</span>
```

The second part is how best to link this JS into the relevant Wordpress page. There is some further info required in response to comments before we can finally decide that, but one important thing to remember is that it must be run after the DOM has loaded.

Note: although the code above answers the question on coding as it was set, it is arguably not the best way of achieving this. Altering HTML 'on the fly' like this might lead to other problems - not least if the plugin developer changes the format of the HTML. Is there some way of altering the plugin e.g. by selecting some setting for currency?

Comment: It works perfectly! 
I set the 'load in footer' parameter to TRUE of the enqueue call and the comma was already a dot(sorry for that), so i did not use that line. 

My knowledge of JS is basic and I could not have come up with a solution like this, so this was a good lesson. Thank you!

Unfortunately there is not a setting for this. The plugin makers use to round the number, but got a lot of requests for a price with cents included, so they changed it.

Luckily I will maintain the site myself, so i can keep an eye on it.